# Finding $y'$ by implicit differentiation if $x^y=y^x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I have it down to $$\ln(y)+(x/y)y' = y'\ln(x)+y/x$$ The problem is factoring out $y'$, which leads to either $$y'=\frac{\ln(y)-(y/x)}{\ln(x)-(x/y)}$$ or to $$y'=\frac{(y/x)-\ln(y)}{(x/y)-\ln(x)}$$ Am I missing something?

Comment: Both your expressions are the same...:) It is just multiplying by (-1) in the numerator and denominator

Comment: I learn something new every day, thanks

Comment: Many of us do, @mirai...and then it is a good day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x^y=y^x\Longrightarrow y\log x=x\log y\Longrightarrow\log x \,dy+\frac{y}{x}dx=\log y\,dx+\frac{x}{y}dy\Longrightarrow$$

$$\left(\log x-\frac{x}{y}\right)dy=\left(\log y-\frac{y}{x}\right)dx\Longrightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\log y-\frac{y}{x}}{\log x-\frac{x}{y}}$$

Comment: Finally understood it, very interesting way of solving the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write

$$e^{y \ln{x}} = e^{x \ln{y}}$$

Then

$$\left (\frac{y}{x}+ y' \ln{x}\right) e^{y \ln{x}} = \left (\ln{y} + \frac{x y'}{y}\right) e^{x \ln{y}}$$

rearranging, we get

$$\left (x^y \ln{x} - \frac{x}{y} y^x\right) y' = y^x \ln{y} - \frac{y}{x} x^y$$

Use $y^x=x^y$ and get

$$y'=\frac{\ln{y}-(y/x)}{\ln{x}-(x/y)}$$

Comment: Not following after the second step, but thank you for writing it out, I'll try to understand it.